# Probability of a cheater being caught given a random check

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

So this problem I made up based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sJxBI3RZUU). I've made three parts to it just to keep things fun

> A bunch of $n$ students take an exam. Out of all the students, $x$ of them are cheaters. A teacher, Bob, has too many students to grade and just checks a random bunch of $y$ papers, where $y \leq n$. If it is guaranteed that a student will be caught cheating if Bob checks their paper, what is the probability that Bob will catch a cheater while grading the exam?

Second follow-up:

> Now let's say Bob is tired and is no longer perfect. He can catch a cheater with a $p$ probability. What is the probability then that he catches a cheater while grading the exam?

Third part:

> Let us say that the $n$ students take one exam each day that is graded instantly. What is the expected number of days until perfect Bob catches his first cheater, and until imperfect Bob catches his first cheater?

Comment: For the 1st and 2nd part, it seems the wording "what is the probability that Bob will catch a cheater" should be interpreted as (a) "given that you are a cheater, what is the chance of you being caught", instead of (b) "what is the chance that Bob catches at least one cheater" since (a) is more interesting than (b). However, in the 3rd part it seems that you have always had (b) as in you mind. So for the first two parts which is it? (a) or (b)? If (b) then it's just a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $n, x, y$ where you want $1 - P(0)$.

Comment: It's (b), but what is a hypergeometric distribution?